# How to exclude Cross apply to make it conditional

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following clause in my query. I have table called service entry and a second table called service entry parts. A service entry record could have multiple service entry parts. The service entry part table has a column called servicetypeids in the following format: Row 1:  1,2,3,     Row 2: 3,4  and so on. I use a Table value function to see what service entries in service parts have the service type id's for example my param could be 1 or 2,3 and so on. That part of the query works fine which I do a cross apply and etc.  What I want to do is if my parametr  @ServiceTypes is NULL then I do not want to search agaiants the servicetypeids column and simply return service entries which exist in service entry part. I wil still be joining with the part table and the part active condition works fine. It got a little complex so though seek help.

```
                        S.ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT ServiceEntryID
                        FROM 
                          ServiceEntryPart M
                          CROSS APPLY
                          dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(M.ServiceTypeIDs, N',') M2
                          JOIN dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@ServiceTypes, N',') P ON M2.Item = P.Item
                          INNER JOIN Part ON M.PartID = Part.ID
                              WHERE 
@ActivePart is null or @ActivePart = Part.Active))
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?